# filtering mechanism inside Google uiApp

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting

I have a table chart that presents every column in my google sheets file.  I would like to limit the columns published to just one hardcoded selection. I have tried several ways with ZERO luck.  How should this work?

```
function doGet(){
  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();

    var ssKey = "XXXXX";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssKey);


    var dataRange = ss.getDataRange();
    var data = dataRange.getDataTable(true);

    var companyFilter = Charts.newStringFilter()
        .setFilterColumnIndex(11)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

uiApp is discontinued.  Try using the HtmlService.  You will have to follow the tutorials on how to set up your apps script using HtmlService.

To create the table that you desire, you can pull the data and create an html table using a function like the following.

```
function drawTable(){
  var htmlOutput = "<table><tr>
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("NAME").getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var y=0;y<data[0].length,y++){
    if((y=(# of column you don't want, remembering that the first column is 0]))||(y=(# of second column))||y=(keep adding columns you don't want to include))){continue;}
    htmlOutput+="<th>"+data[0][y]+"</th>";

  }
  htmlOutput+="</tr><tr>";
  for(var x=1;x<data.length;x++){
    htmlOutput+="<tr>";
    for(var y=0;y<data[x].length;y++){
      if(same parameters as above){continue;}
      htmlOutput+="<td>"+data[x][y]+"</td>";
      }
   htmlOutput+="</tr>";
   }
return htmlOutput;
}
```